# How to Set Up Web Disk with Nautilus in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, webdav

I have a folder on my system (running Ubuntu 11.10) that I want to be synced to a directory on my personal server (running CentOS / Cpanel). This is how I am trying to achieve it...

- Set up a web disk
- use 'Grsync' tool to sync my local folder to my server (which is now just another directory - - web disk)

So, I guess you get my point. But I don't understand how to setup a web disk. These are the instructions:

[image: Ubuntu setting up a web disk]

I opened Nautilus, which is just the window manager. But I do not see the address bar. I also checked folder preferences, and it's not there. So, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the address bar in Nautilus with <kbd>ctrl-L</kbd>.

You can also use the "Connect to Server" wizard from the file menu to connect to WebDAV shares.